# database of 12-tone rows

Tags: learning-resources, atonal, serial

I am hoping to do some statistical analysis on 12-tone rows that have been employed in practice, and for this I'm looking for as large as possible a database.

Currently I am only aware of the 160 something rows on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tone_rows_and_series)
and a humdrum archive of rows from Schoenberg, Berg, and Webern (http://www.ccarh.org/publications/data/humdrum/tonerow/).

But given the prevalence of serial composition in (especially American) academic music for so many years mid-century, I have hopes that there's much more out there!!

Many thanks for pointers to any relevant resources!!

Answer (score 2):

You might check out the online database by Harald Fripertinger and Peter Lackner [here](http://math047129.uni-graz.at/fripertinger/db/).

There's also a search page [here](http://143.50.47.149/cgi-bin/music/music.cgi).

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Where was this article published?

Comment: I believe aparente001 is referring to this work:
http://homepage.uni-graz.at/de/haraldfripertinger/database-on-tone-rows-and-tropes/
(The paper in the Journal of mathematics and music is probably more complete, but i can't currently access...)
Parts of this are interesting and relevant to me in what aspects of rows to analyze, but right now I am looking for a database of tone rows used **In practice,** not just existing in theory (there are only !11, easily enumerated).

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but Fripertinger has a home page where he links to a "database": http://math047129.uni-graz.at/fripertinger/db/.  I suppose you've already googled this up down and sideways?  In addition, it looks like Fripertinger would be someone to write to, to see if he has any additional suggestions.  Also I suggest you look at his papers -- try interlibrary loan.

Comment: No this is actually great! I had visited the database before but had missed this search page (http://143.50.47.149/cgi-bin/music/music.cgi), where you can get 1373 rows with an empty query :) hehe, thank you for posting or i wouldn't have revisited more carefully.  Will leave the question open for a bit in case someone else wants to offer more resources, but this is extremely helpful.

Comment: but maybe you could edit your answer for completeness (and convenience?)

Comment: Sorry.  It's your project!  If you want to edit my answer for me, fine, if you want to leave this slightly messy, that's okay with me.  I was just hoping to get you unstuck.  Which I guess we did together.  A team effort!